# How can you delete a scrip from an R,project

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a project with multiple scripts I know how to clear the console and how to use rm to remove the variables I create.  I have tried using the x on the upper right of the scrip.R tabs I want to delete and then saving the project after deletion.  When I re-open the project those scripts I deleted are back on again.

thanks for any help.  tried the RStudio help and  R documentation as well as the search here

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you trying to close files, or delete them? Scripts are just files, you can delete them just like you would anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If by scripts you mean files in your RStudio project directory, you can delete them on the file tab of the bottom right pane. Select the file and click the delete button.
The x on the upper right just closes the editing session for that file.
If by scripts you mean R functions, they can be deleted like any other variable.
rm(functionName)
or
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a script by clicking the white box next to it in the project environment and then clicking the delete button in that same environment.

[image: Checked White Box with Delete Button Above]

You can also delete by going into file explorer where your project is located on your machine and delete just like any other file.